# How to add container or panel in flash and resize them using actionscript 3.0

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash

I want to show some image in a flash. When I click an image, the image is up as like as image shown below.[image]

[image]

when i click the image: [image]

but the problem is when i click the image in that group, there is a gap between images. I want to attach them. I can not solve the problem. please anybody help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex, this is fairly trivial. You set the cards in an `HGroup` (calculating the `gap` will be difficult, but not impossible) and simply remove selected cards from that group and place them in another. After the card is removed, your other cards will be realigned by the layout automatically.

If you're not using Flex, I suggest extracting the code you used to layout the cards in the first place into a separate function. When a card is selected, you move the card out of the `DisplayObjectContainer` it is currently in and place it in another and then simply call the layout function again. This is the same method as I would use with Flex, although a little less automated due to the lack of Flex's layout engine.

Comment: But when i used 
`var container1:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
container1.widht = 500; 
container1.height = 500`
then no card display in the table. 
And without width and height card display.
Whats the problem to set width and height.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are saying (not enough information). Please edit your question with these details and a code sample. As a rule of thumb, you should generally *always* post code samples on StackOverflow (it makes it much easier for us to help)